# JavaScript function find and change CSS of column if it has more than one DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm trying to get JavaScript to to change the color of a column and add a msg variable if it contains more than 2 div elements. My code is below and I know it's unfinished so hoping for some guidance.

I'm not using jQuery just browser JS.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>Column B</th>       
    </tr>

    <tr id="row">
        <td id="columnA">
            <div id="d1"></div>
        </td>
        <td id="columnB">
            <div id="d1"></div>
            <div id="d2"></div>
            <div id="d3"></div>
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
function alertTooMany() {
    var row = document.getElementById('row'), // Get Row
    var col = row.getElementsByTagName('td'), // Get Columns in row
    var div = col.getElementsByTagName('div'), // Get Div in columns
    var num = divs.length; // count DIV tags

            // prepare and display message
            if (num < 2) { // If number of divs is less than 2
                msg = "Column Open";
            }
            else if (num > 2){ // If number of divs is greater than 2
                msg = "Warn: Column overfull!";
            }
            else { // If number of divs is 2
                msg = "Column Full"; 
            }
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have `var num = divs.length;`, but no variable named `divs`. Using any reasonably good IDE will highlight mistakes like these, get one.

Comment: How are you calling the function `alertTooMany()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't have any element with id `message` in your HTML. And you JavaScript code had some errors.

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnnuzrcz/1/)

#### HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column A</th>
        <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row">
        <td id="columnA">
            <div id="d1">1</div>
        </td>
        <td id="columnB">
            <div id="d1">1</div>
            <div id="d2">2</div>
            <div id="d3">3</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="message"></div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function alertTooMany() {
    var row = document.getElementById('row'), // Get Row
        col = row.getElementsByTagName('td'); // Get Columns in row

    for (i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var div = col[i].getElementsByTagName('div');
        var num = div.length;
        if (num < 2) { // If number of divs is less than 2
            msg = "Column Open";
        } else if (num > 2) { // If number of divs is greater than 2
            msg = "Warn: Column overfull!";
            for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
                div[i].style.color = 'red';
            }
        } else { // If number of divs is 2
            msg = "Column Full";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
}
alertTooMany();
```

Comment: Yeah see, I don't know my for statements yet. Thanks very much for this, I'll go check it out then come back to mark as answered. Thanks again!

Comment: Worked exactly as requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function alertTooMany() {
        var row = document.getElementById('row'); // Get Row
        var cols = row.getElementsByTagName('td'); // Get Columns in row

        // Iterating through columns
        for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
            var col = cols[i];

            var divs = col.getElementsByTagName('div'); // Get Div in column
            var num = divs.length; // count DIV tags

            // prepare and display message
            if (num < 2) { // If number of divs is less than 2
                msg = "Column Open";
            }
            else if (num > 2){ // If number of divs is greater than 2
                msg = "Warn: Column overfull!";

                // Finding header with same index as overfull column
                var headers = document.querySelectorAll('th');
                var matchingHeader = headers[i];

                if (matchingHeader) {
                    matchingHeader.style['color'] = 'red';
                }

                col.style['color'] = 'red';
            }
            else { // If number of divs is 2
                msg = "Column Full"; 
            }
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = msg;
        }
    }

    alertTooMany();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I found this helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Column A</th>
    <th>Column B</th>
</tr>
<tr id="row">
    <td id="columnA">
        <div id="d1">01</div>
        <span class="message"></span>
    </td>
    <td id="columnB">
        <div id="d1">11</div>
        <div id="d2">12</div>
        <div id="d3">13</div>
        <span class="message"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function alertTooMany() {
    var row = document.getElementById('row'); // Get Row
    var tds = row.getElementsByTagName('td'); // Get Columns in row

    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        var divs = tds[i].getElementsByTagName('div'); // Get Div in columns
        num = divs.length; // count DIV tags
        // prepare and display message
        if (num < 2) { // If number of divs is less than 2
            msg = "Column Open";
            tds[i].style.color="green";
        } else if (num > 2){ // If number of divs is greater than 2
            msg = "Warn: Column overfull!";
            tds[i].style.color="red";
        } else { // If number of divs is 2
            msg = "Column Full"; 
        }
        document.getElementsByClassName("message")[i].innerHTML = msg;
    }
}
</script>
```